# Cannot find the path for General Assembly Cache folder

Tags: asp.net

Mine is windows 7 32-bit OS. Can someone tell me where I can find General Assembly Cache folder?

Comment: It would really help if you can explain why you would want to know this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be here : C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly

Or you can type `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\` in Run dialog.

And you probably mean the Global Assembly Cache folder.

Comment: doesn't this change in .net 4 or 4.5?

Comment: I've .NET 4.5 installed. The GAC folder shows up in the above location.

Comment: sorry, I thought you had something else there, before.  For reference, anything targeting 3.5 or below may be in %windir%\assembly